# ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all() how can i use them?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, machine-learning, model, any

i got this error while trying to predict the machine learning model for single batch

but i do not know how to use **any()** or **all()** in my code i think because of the size of array at least

i have to use one of them **any()** or **all()**

Code:

```
saved_weights = find_checkpoint_file('.')
print('please enter the value')
user_input1 = input()
if len(saved_weights) == 0:
    print("The network hasn't been trained! Program will exit...")
    sys.exit()
else:
    X_test = load_test_data(user_input1, X_word_to_ix, MAX_LEN)
    print(type(X_test))
    X_test = pad_sequences(X_test, maxlen=4, dtype='int32')
    print(type(X_test))
    model.load_weights(saved_weights)
    predictions = np.array(model.predict(X_test))
    print(type(predictions))
    sequences = []
    for prediction in predictions:
        sequence = ' '.join([y_ix_to_word[index] for index in prediction if index > 0])
        print(sequence)
        l = sequences.append(sequence)
    np.savetxt('test_result.txt', sequences, fmt='%s')
```

the line that i think though out the error:

```
sequence = ' '.join([y_ix_to_word[index] for index in prediction if index > 0])
```

**error:**

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is
>   ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
>
> ```
> sequence = ' '.join([y_ix_to_word[index] for index in prediction if index > 0])
> ```
>
> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than
>   one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

in the below image is the traceback of error
[traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qw2aO.png)

Comment: Always post **the whole error message** with **full traceback** please.

Comment: yes sorry i just update with log message

Comment: That's not the traceback.

Comment: yes sorry i just uploaded the image of traceback

Comment: It looks like `index` is a numpy array, so `index > 0` doesn't make sense (it returns a boolean array).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062954/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous)

Comment: so what do i have to do? any idea

Comment: well he is working with csv and dataframe but iam working with txt